# Plot only upper triangle of the matrix using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a matrix that I already cut into the upper triangle:

```
eSim <- c(1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1)
dim(eSim) <- c(4,4)
rownames(eSim)=c("PosLong\n1200", "PosLong\n1800", "Neglong\n1200", "Neglong\n1800")
colnames(eSim)=c("PosLong\n1200", "PosLong\n1800", "Neglong\n1200", "Neglong\n1800")

# Get upper triangle of the correlation matrix
  get_upper_tri <- function(cormat){
    cormat[lower.tri(cormat)]<- NA
    return(cormat)
  }
eSim_upper <- get_upper_tri(eSim)
melted_eSim_upper <- melt(eSim_upper, na.rm = TRUE)
```

And this is my code for plotting this matrix

```
ggplot(data = melted_eSim_upper, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = as.factor(value)))+
 geom_tile(color = "black", size=0.8)+
 scale_fill_manual(values=c("#8DD3C7", "#FB8072"))+
 theme_minimal()+ 
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, 
    size = 12, hjust = 1))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, 
    size = 12, hjust = 1))+
 coord_fixed()+
 theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
  axis.title.y = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  panel.border = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 50)))
```

The outcome:

[image]

I have several questions to acheive my final goal:

1. Is there a way to rotate this plot diagnoally? Something like this:
   [image]
2. Is there a way to move the y axis text further away to the matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, use `limits = rev` in a discrete scale.
2. Yes, but the more convenient thing to do is to use `guide = guide_axis(angle = 45)` instead of micromanaging the theme settings.

```r
library(ggplot2)

eSim <- c(1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1)
dim(eSim) <- c(4,4)
rownames(eSim)=c("PosLong\n1200", "PosLong\n1800", "Neglong\n1200", "Neglong\n1800")
colnames(eSim)=c("PosLong\n1200", "PosLong\n1800", "Neglong\n1200", "Neglong\n1800")

# Get upper triangle of the correlation matrix
get_upper_tri <- function(cormat){
  cormat[lower.tri(cormat)]<- NA
  return(cormat)
}
eSim_upper <- get_upper_tri(eSim)
melted_eSim_upper <- reshape2::melt(eSim_upper, na.rm = TRUE)

ggplot(data = melted_eSim_upper, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = as.factor(value)))+
  geom_tile(color = "black", size=0.8)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#8DD3C7", "#FB8072"))+
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev, guide = guide_axis(angle = 45)) +
  theme_minimal()+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, 
                                   size = 12, hjust = 1))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12))+
  coord_fixed()+
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>